# How to convert Map[Map[String,Int],Int] into Map[String,Int] in scala?

Tags: scala

Eg. `Map[Map[String,Int],Int]` I need to convert it into `Map[String,Int]` i.e Int in value part of inner map is replaced with Int in value part of outer map.

For example:

```
val innerMap = Map("a"->1)
val outerMap = Map(innerMap, 2)
```

Required result:

```
resultMap = Map("a"->2)
```

Comment: Consider: `Map(Map("a"->1)->11,Map("a"->2)->22)` Should the result be `"a"->11` or `"a"->22`?

Comment: yes that which **@jwvh** asked and also what if we have `Map(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2) -> 3))`?

Comment: Map("a" -> 3 , "b" -> 3)

Answer (score 3):

Even though you haven't answered my question about duplicate `String` values, I'm going to guess that what you want is something like this.

```
val mmsii :Map[Map[String,Int],Int] =
  Map(Map("a"->1)->11,Map("b"->2)->22)

mmsii.flatMap{case (m,v) => m.keys.map(_ -> v)}
```

Or, using the sometimes friendlier `for` comprehension:

```
for {
  (m,v) <- mmsii
  (k,_) <- m
} yield k->v
```

Keep in mind, if there are duplicate `String` keys then only one `String->Int` pair will be retained and the others will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage this solution to your problem

```
    val anotherMap = Map(Map("a" -> 1) -> 10, Map("b" -> 2) -> 11, Map("c" -> 3) -> 12)

    anotherMap.flatMap {
  case (keyMap, value) =>
    keyMap map {
      case (k, _) => Map(k -> value)
    }
}

// res0: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(a -> 10), Map(b -> 11), Map(c -> 12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same as **@jwvh**'s solution, just a little more *explicit*

```
val nestedMap: Map[Map[String, Int], Int] = Map(
  Map("k1" -> 1) -> 11,
  Map("k2" -> 2, "k3" -> 3) -> 22
)

val unnestedMap: Map[String, Int] = nestedMap.flatMap { (outerTuple: (Map[String, Int], Int)) =>
  val innerMap: Map[String, Int] = outerTuple._1
  val commonVal: Int = outerTuple._2
  innerMap.map { (innerTuple: (String, Int)) =>
    (innerTuple._1 -> commonVal)
  }
}
print(unnestedMap)
```